# Invalid syntax python starred expressions

Tags: python, iterable-unpacking

I am trying to unpack set of phone numbers from a sequence, python shell in turn throws an invalid syntax error. I am using python 2.7.1. Here is the snippet

```
 >>> record = ('Dave', 'dave@example.com', '773-555-1212', '847-555-1212')
 >>> name, email, *phone-numbers = record
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
 >>>
```

Please explain. Is there any other way of doing the same?

Answer (score 19):

You are using Python 3 specific syntax in Python 2.

The `*` syntax for extended iterable unpacking in assignments is not available in Python 2.

See [Python 3.0, new syntax](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#new-syntax) and [PEP 3132](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/).

Use a function with `*` splat argument unpacking to simulate the same behaviour in Python 2:

```
def unpack_three(arg1, arg2, *rest):
    return arg1, arg2, rest

name, email, phone_numbers = unpack_three(*user_record)
```

or use list slicing.

Answer (score 14):

This new syntax was [introduced in Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#new-syntax). So, it'll raise error in Python 2.

Related PEP: [PEP 3132 -- Extended Iterable Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)

```
name, email, *phone_numbers = user_record
```

Python 3:

```
>>> a, b, *c = range(10)
>>> a
0
>>> b
1
>>> c
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Python 2:

```
>>> a, b, *c = range(10)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a,b,*c = range(10)
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>
```

Answer (score 8):

That functionality is only available in Python 3, an alternative is:

```
name, email, phone_numbers = record[0], record[1], record[2:]
```

Or something like:

```
>>> def f(name, email, *phone_numbers):
        return name, email, phone_numbers

>>> f(*record)
('Dave', 'dave@example.com', ('773-555-1212', '847-555-1212'))
```

but that is pretty hacky IMO